# Setting to have added object appear in scene collection root instead of a group inside?

Tags: collections

I am still getting used to the new `scene collection` feature. It's great but there's one behaviour that freaks me out. Whenever I add a new meshes it appears in one of the groups. Usually my workflow needs it in the main scene collection.

**Q:** Is there a global setting to get added meshes being moved in the main scene collection instead of a group inside automatically?

Comment: The new object is created in the collection which is selected in the outliner.

Comment: Inside the collection I have multiple groups (folders). If I hide a group, that group is still selected and everytime I add an object I have to manually deselect the group additionally. A step I don't need and always forget. My question is, if one can avoid this default behaviour.